# Java: ArrayList not De/Serializing Correctly

Tags: java, android

I am making an App where you can create lists that will pick a random choice. In this app I pick a random entry in the list. The app serializes the ArrayList into a txt file. I am making the part where it deserializes the ArrayList and opens a new activity with that info. Problem is that it forcloses on opening that activity. I beleive it has something to do with it not serializing right. Anyhelp would be awesome, thanks!

BTW The reason it forecloses is the ArrayList that is deserialized is empty.

Here is the first Java file:

```
package com.frostbytedev.randomgenie;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Steven on 6/11/13.
 */
public class NewList extends Activity implements Serializable, View.OnClickListener{
    String ListName;
    String ItemText;
    int i = 0;

    List<String> List = new ArrayList<String>();
    Button save;
    EditText FileName, etItem1, etItem2, etItem3, etItem4, etItem5;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.newlist);
        initilize();
    }

    private void IndexList() {
        List.add(FileName.getText().toString());
        List.add(etItem1.getText().toString());
        List.add(etItem2.getText().toString());
        List.add(etItem3.getText().toString());
        List.add(etItem4.getText().toString());
        List.add(etItem5.getText().toString());

        for(i=1;i<5;i++){
            ItemText = List.get(i);
            if(ItemText.contentEquals("")){
                List.remove(List.get(i));
            }
        }

    }

    private void initilize() {
        save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bSave);
        FileName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etFileName);
        etItem1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etItem1);
        etItem2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etItem2);
        etItem3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etItem3);
        etItem4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etItem4);
        etItem5 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etItem5);
        save.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch(view.getId()){

            case R.id.bSave:
                IndexList();
                try {
                    SaveList();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


        }
    }


    private void SaveList() throws IOException {
        String filename = FileName.getText().toString()+".txt";
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = openFileOutput(filename,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            out.writeObject(List);
            out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}
```

And the second:

```
package com.frostbytedev.randomgenie;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Steven on 6/15/13.
 */
public class ListSelect extends ListActivity implements Serializable {
    List<String> List = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> textFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> ListStrings = new ArrayList<String>();

    List<String> textFiles(String directory) {
        File dir = new File(directory);
        for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
            if (file.getName().endsWith((".txt"))) {
                textFiles.add(file.getName().replace(".txt", ""));
            }
        }
        return textFiles;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, textFiles("data/data/com.frostbytedev.randomgenie/files")));
    }
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
            String FileName = textFiles.get(position);
        deserialize(FileName);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        Intent OpenList = new Intent(this, ListRandom.class);
        OpenList.putExtra("ListItem1",List.get(1));
        OpenList.putExtra("ListItem2", List.get(2));
        OpenList.putExtra("ListItem3", List.get(3));
        OpenList.putExtra("ListItem4",List.get(4));
        OpenList.putExtra("ListItem5", List.get(5));
        startActivity(OpenList);

    }

    private void deserialize(String filename) {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        ObjectInputStream in = null;
        ObjectOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
            in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            List = (ArrayList<String>) in.readObject();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

LogCat:

```
06-19 00:00:53.497    8447-8447/com.frostbytedev.randomgenie   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
        at com.frostbytedev.randomgenie.ListSelect.onListItemClick(ListSelect.java:44)
        at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: LogCat added, any help?

Comment: 'List' is a very bad choice for variable name

Comment: @AndyRoyD. Why don't you pass directly the list to the intent ? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putStringArrayListExtra(java.lang.String, java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>)

Comment: Which line is ListSelect.java:44?

Comment: Intent OpenList = new Intent(this, ListRandom.class);

Comment: That's probably line 43 not 44, so my guess is the OpenList.putExtra("ListItem1",List.get(1)); throws the exception which matches my answer

Comment: Why do you post the same question twice? There's nothing wrong with your app, it's just a big mess in terms of design and coding style. That's why it doesn't run and that's why it's so hard to find this trivial bug. Furthermore you provide just half the information needed to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Method `deserialize` is **not on the stacktrace**, therefore the error lines in empty list `FileName`.

```
String FileName = textFiles.get(position);
```

Comment: Okay makes sense, but what should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

When reading the files from the file system you cut the txt extension:

```
textFiles.add(file.getName().replace(".txt", ""))
```

When you click the item you use that file name to deserialize the list. The original file was written using the txt extension though and so the file won't be found and the deserialization fails, the list is empty and List.get(1) will throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException.
What you could do is:

```
fis = new FileInputStream(filename+".txt");
```

I'm pretty sure you logcat output also has a FileNotFoundException above the IndexOutOfBoundsException.

BTW it's a really bad idea to name a variable like a method. Use getTextFiles() for the method if the variable is called textFiles.

Comment: Ahah.... Very good find but It gets the same error

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace you get in the deserialization method? There must be output from the ex.printStackTrace();